# Работа GC при использовании Set в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, память, коллекции, сборщик-мусора

Есть парочка вопросов по работе Garbage Collector при использовании объектов `Set` в Node.JS.

1. Срабатывает ли GC после того, как вызвать метод `.clear()` для объекта `Set`?
2. Каким образом лучше всего очищать `set`?
3. Команда `set = null;` приводит ли к вызову GC для всех объектов, что лежали в `set`?

Answer (score 4):

Пара слов о сборке мусора:

**Когда** сработает [garbage collector (gc)](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) **выбирает v8**, я не знаю деталей, но предполагаю что там очень **кучерявая логика** основанная на алгоритме [Mark and Sweep](http://wiki.c2.com/?MarkAndSweep)

[image: mark-sweep]

Если объект недостижим по ссылкам, [теоретически](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/memory-leaks-in-nodejs-quick-overview-988c23b24dba) gc должен его уничтожить.

---

Если все таки хочется вызвать gc вручную, это можно, однако понадобится бубен 
**Настоятельно рекомендую так не делать**

```
 node --expose-gc app.js
```

После этого в можно в приложении попросить gc прибраться.

```
global.gc();
```

Только он все равно ничего не уберет, если на объект кто то ссылается и Вы это не учли.

---

Теперь коротко по пунктам.

1. Нет, gc сработает тогда, когда решит рантайм.
2. Если вы имеете в виду очистку содержимого самого объекта `Set`, то что вы сделали `.clear()`  этого достаточно, если Вы хотите чтобы так же `gc` собрал те объекты, которые лежали в `Set`, вам надо убедиться, что на них нет больше ссылок.
3. См пункт 2

Comment: поставлю вам плюс, только поправьте `--expose-gc`